# jQuery: keep affected only last clicked element

Tags: jquery, css

I have simple code where when user clicks on chevron jquery show hided content.

This elements in my whole code I have 2.

Now question, is there any solution how to keep affected only last clicked element?

So when I click on first, first hided content will be showed and when I click on second element which hows second hided content first will be hided again.

```js
$('.chevron').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // for you css .chevron.active
  $(this).parent().parent().find('p').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.chevron {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10px;
}

.chevron.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

p.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="fix-broken-links" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fix-broken-links">Fix broken links</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="spelling-grammar" type="checkbox">
    <label for="spelling-grammar">Spelling & grammar</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by removing `active` class from `.chevron` or any `p` tag which previously had the active class like:

```
var $ptag = $(this).closest('.column').find('p');
$('.chevron.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
$('p.active').not($ptag).removeClass('active');
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.chevron').click(function() {

  var $ptag = $(this).closest('.column').find('p');
  $('.chevron.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $('p.active').not($ptag).removeClass('active');

  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // for you css .chevron.active
  $ptag.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.chevron {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10px;
}

.chevron.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: none;
}

p.active {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="fix-broken-links" type="checkbox">
    <label for="fix-broken-links">Fix broken links</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <input id="spelling-grammar" type="checkbox">
    <label for="spelling-grammar">Spelling & grammar</label>
    <img class="chevron" src="https://supersede.space/chevron.svg" alt="Checklist chevron">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>SKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuskaSKuska skuska</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in case you have one chevron open and you try to open the other one, the first one should be closed. In this case you can achieve this by closing all chevrons before opening the chevron you need, a quick adjustment would be:

```
$('.chevron').click(function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active'); //close all of them
  $(this).addClass('active'); // activate what you need  
  $(this).parent().parent().find('p').addClass('active');
});
```

A faster code would require you to store the activated elements, and close those instead of scanning over the entire DOM, I leave that to you.